# NetBeans IDE: "Run Success" Output Occurs Before Output Finishes

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

I made a C program that prints out a lot of values from a binary file. I believe the program finishes it's functions and ends before it actually displays values it spits out. So as a result I get a lovely `RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 198ms)` plopped right in the middle of my nicely formatted output, successfully screwing with the continuity of the rest. Is there a non-intrusive way to fix this?

I have tried a while loop encasing main's return value with a `scanf()` to pause the program until the user enters any value other than `0` but I'd prefer it if I could just have it run like a 'normal' program which in this case is without any user input. Thanks in advance for any advice or tips. :)

Comment: [Looks like a bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=214423).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jesse Good is right, this used to be a bug in NetBeans. So you can try the following:

a) Check if you flush your buffer, i.e., if you use printf(), the output is buffered before it is actually written to the console. Try to use `fflush(stdout);` before `return`. (But I guess thats not it. Actually the buffer should be flushed automatically before return, so I don't think this will fix it, but you never know :-) )

b) Check that you have the latest Version (v7.3, 2013-02-21), as the bug was fixed in Nightly Build 2012-09-21. Maybe even v7.2.1, 2012-10-22 is sufficient, but v7.2 is definitely not.

-Hannes

Comment: Thank you for the detail and ideas on solutions. I mainly wanted to know whether or not it was something I was doing wrong so this answers my question just fine. :)

Comment: And thank you for the edit. X) Can't believe I let that typo get by! :D